# Runtime Error 3134 Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble identifying the root cause of my problem with the error.

below is my SQL statement

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Kids(ID,First,Last,Age,Gender,Race,Org,School,Address,City,State,Zip,Name_of_Parent_Guardian,Parent_Guardian_Phone,Parent_Guardian_Email_Address,Child_s_Phone,Child_s_Email_Address,Siblings_Who_Participated_in_KIF,Years_Participated_in_KIF,On_Facebook_Y_or_N,On_Pic_Pals_Y_or_N,Notes_Comments,Year" & _
"Value ('" & "','" & Me.First.Value & "','" & Me.Last.Value & "','" & Me.Age.Value & "','" & Me.Gender.Value & "','" & Me.Race.Value & "','" & Me.Org.Value & "','" & Me.School.Value & "','" & Me.Address.Value & "','" & Me.City.Value & "','" & Me.State.Value & "','" & Me.Zip.Value & "','" & Me.NameofparentG.Value & "','" & Me.parentphone.Value & "','" & Me.parentemail.Value & "','" & Me.Child_sphone.Value & "','" & Me.Child_sEmailAddress.Value & "','" & Me.Sibling_s_WhoParticipatedinKIF.Value & "','" & Me.Year_ParticipatedinKIF.Value & "','" & Me.OnFacebook_Y_or_N_.Value & "','" & Me.NotesComments.Value & "','" & Me.Year.Value & "')"
```

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend storing the concatenated value that the above resolves to in a a string variable and printing out that value instead of the kludge above.  I see a open ( for the columns names but no close ) to start off with.  perhaps it's as simple as `...Notes_comments,Year)"` perhaps not... which is why I'd prefer to also see the statement being executed not just the code.  open to SQL injection one would think.

Answer (score 1):

check your syntax ...

it should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: Hi BWS, the syntax is what I am using for visual basic in a Microsoft access form. You have to call CurrentDb.Execute first then proceed with the sql insert statement.

Comment: @dtshack = `"... ,Notes_Comments,YearValue (..."` is not the same as `"... ,Notes_Comments,Year) Values (..."` - check your syntax.

Comment: Great answers everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be emphasized enough: consider using a parameterized query which avoids quote handling and variable concatenation for a more readable, maintainable, and safer code. Access SQL allows the `PARAMETERS` clause to specify named parameters with defined types which can be called with a [Querydef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) in VBA.

**SQL** *(save as a stored query in database, adjust types and sizes as needed)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [IDParam] TEXT(255), [FirstParam] TEXT(255), [LastParam] TEXT(255), [AgeParam] TEXT(255), [GenderParam] TEXT(255), 
           [RaceParam] TEXT(255), [OrgParam] TEXT(255), [SchoolParam] TEXT(255), [AddressParam] TEXT(255), [CityParam] TEXT(255), 
           [StateParam] TEXT(255), [ZipParam] TEXT(255), [NameofparentGParam] TEXT(255), [parentphoneParam] TEXT(255), 
           [parentemailParam] TEXT(255), [Child_sphoneParam] TEXT(255), [Child_sEmailAddressParam] TEXT(255),
           [Sibling_s_WhoParticipatedinKIFParam] TEXT(255), [Year_ParticipatedinKIFParam] TEXT(255), 
           [OnFacebook_Y_or_N_Param] TEXT(255), [NotesCommentsParam] TEXT(255), [YearParam] TEXT(255);

INSERT INTO Kids ([ID], [First], [Last], Age, Gender, Race, Org, School, Address, City, State, Zip,
                  Name_of_Parent_Guardian, Parent_Guardian_Phone, Parent_Guardian_Email_Address,
                  Child_s_Phone, Child_s_Email_Address, Siblings_Who_Participated_in_KIF,
                  Years_Participated_in_KIF, On_Facebook_Y_or_N, On_Pic_Pals_Y_or_N,Notes_Comments, [Year])
VALUES ([IDParam], [FirstParam], [LastParam], [AgeParam], [GenderParam], [RaceParam], 
        [OrgParam], [SchoolParam], [AddressParam], [CityParam], [StateParam], [ZipParam], 
        [NameofparentGParam], [parentphoneParam], [parentemailParam], [Child_sphoneParam], 
        [Child_sEmailAddressParam], [Sibling_s_WhoParticipatedinKIFParam], [Year_ParticipatedinKIFParam], 
        [OnFacebook_Y_or_N_Param], [NotesCommentsParam], [YearParam]);
```

**VBA** *(dynamically pass values to named parameters, then execute)*

```vb
Dim db As Database
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("myQueryName")

qdef![IDParam] = Me.ID
qdef![FirstParam] = Me.First
qdef![LastParam] = Me.Last
qdef![AgeParam] = Me.Age
qdef![GenderParam] = Me.Gender 
qdef![RaceParam] = Me.Race
qdef![OrgParam] = Me.Org
qdef![SchoolParam] = Me.School 
qdef![AddressParam] = Me.Address
qdef![CityParam] = Me.City
qdef![StateParam] = Me.[State]
qdef![ZipParam] = Me.Zip
qdef![NameofparentGParam] = Me.NameofparentG
qdef![parentphoneParam] = Me.parentphone 
qdef![parentemailParam] = Me.parentemail 
qdef![Child_sphoneParam] = Me.Child_sphone
qdef![Child_sEmailAddressParam] = Me.Child_sEmailAddress
qdef![Sibling_s_WhoParticipatedinKIFParam] = Me.Sibling_s_WhoParticipatedinKIF
qdef![Year_ParticipatedinKIFParam] = Me.Year_ParticipatedinKIF
qdef![OnFacebook_Y_or_N_Param] = Me.OnFacebook_Y_or_N_ 
qdef![NotesCommentsParam] = Me.NotesCommentsParam 
qdef![YearParam] = Me.YearParam

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```